# Is there a Oracle Coherence Java stub?

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-coherence

Is there a Oracle Coherence Java stub that I can use in my test suits?

I would like to find a piece of software that pretends to be Oracle Coherence and that will return what i tell it to.

Answer (score 3):

LittleGrid does that extremely well.  We use it to unit test our Coherence code.

http://littlegrid.bitbucket.org